# Avoid NumberFormatException in Spring MVC controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

In my Spring MVC controller I have a method like this:

```
public String myMethod(@RequestParam(defaultValue="0") int param) { ... }
```

When I pass a string as value of my `param` I'm obviously getting a `NumberFormatException`:

> Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'int'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "test"

That's clear...

So I'm trying to find a way to redirect user to a default page when this error is occurring. Is there a common way to achieve this?

At the moment I'm thinking about using a `String` in place of an `int` to map my `param`, check if this is parsable to `int` and then switch to the appropriate logic, but this seems a workaround, not a solution...

Is there a more elegant way to handle this problem and keep the correct type binding for my `param`?

Comment: You can create an @ControllerAdvice class that could handle Exception such as NumberFormatException, while throwing that exception from your method and send the user to a dedicated error message

Comment: @DamCx ok, but I need to redirect only in this case, not for all the `NumberFormatException` thrown across my application

Comment: Then, create a specific exception to throw in that case, but you will have to check for it in you method, because the @ControllerAdvice class won't be able to distinguish it otherwise.
What I'm not really sure about is how SpringMVC will handle exceptions if they're not specifically thrown by your method

Comment: For controller-specific exception handling: https://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc#controller-based-exception-handling

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally solved adding a `CustomNumberEditor` like this:

```
@InitBinder
public void registerNumbersBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
    binder.registerCustomEditor(Integer.class, new CustomNumberEditor(Integer.class, true){
        @Override
        public void setAsText(String text) throws IllegalArgumentException {
            try{
                super.setAsText(text);
            }catch (IllegalArgumentException ex){
                setValue(0);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look into the @Valid annotation. Hope this helps. This annotation helps in adding more validations for the request parameter.

https://spring.io/guides/gs/validating-form-input/

Answer (score -1):

In this scenario, you need to handle "MethodArgumentTypeMismatchException"
you can do that using @ControllerAdvice